# Updating dictionary values set to properties automatically

Tags: c#, dictionary, mvvm

I have a dictionary where the keys are strings, and the values properties in the same class. How do I update the values automatically when I update the properties?

Here's relevant section of the model class:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
public Dictionary<string, string> Fields
{
    get
    {
        return _fields;
    }
}

public GPHDTModel()
{
    _fields.Add("MessageID", MessageID);
}

private string _messageID;
public string MessageID
{
    get { return _messageID; }
    set { _messageID = value; OnPropertyChanged("MessageID"); }
}
```

Here's relevant section of viewmodel:

```
GPHDTModel gphdtModel = new GPHDTModel();

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    gphdtModel.MessageID = "3";
}
```

So, there's a key "MessageID" with a value of `MessageID`. I set `MessageID` to 3, but the value in the dictionary stays null. I've messed around with the `OnPropertyChanged` event, and tried implementing an `ObservableDictionary` as well, but no luck.

Comment: "How do I update the values automatically when I update the properties?" - you change your property setter so that it updates the dictionary, or you make your `OnPropertyChanged` method do it instead... But basically, something needs to call `_fields["MessageID"] = MessageID;` or equivalent each time it changes...

Comment: You can't add a key that already exists in the dictionary.  So you replace with _fields[key_name] = new value;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In constructor you are adding current message id *value* (which is null) to dictionary:

```
_fields.Add("MessageID", MessageID);
```

You should note that you are adding current value of `MessageID` property here. It's not like adding something like link to the property. You are adding only result of property getter call. If property value will change, the value which is stored in the dictionary will not be modified.

To synchronize values which are stored in the property and in the dictionary you should update dictionary as well when property is modified:

```
private string _messageID;
public string MessageID
{
  get { return _messageID; }
  set { 
      _messageID = value; 
      _fields["MessageID"] = value; // here
      OnPropertyChanged("MessageID");
  }
}
```

You can get rid of this synchronization if you'll use dictionary as the backing storage for properties:

```
public GPHDTModel()
{
    _fields.Add("MessageID", null); // initialize with default value
}
public string MessageID
{
    get { return _fields["MessageID"]; }
    set {
       if (_fields["MessageID"] == value)
          return;

       _fields["MessageID"] = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("MessageID");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
public string MessageID
{
    get { return _messageID; }
    set 
    { 
        _messageID = value;
        Fields["MessageID"] = value
        OnPropertyChanged("MessageID");
    }
}
```

**Reason:**
When you did `_fields.Add("MessageID", MessageID);`, you stored the value in the dictionary, but the link was not there. So when you update the property the value in dictionary remain the same.

TBH, I don't see why you have to do this. Since you have tagged mvvm so i am assuming WPF, but I still can't comprehend why you have to do this.